# java generic math arithmetic for double and float type

Tags: java, generics

I have a class. Most of the functions are for arithmetic. And I would like this class to either float or double as the type, and then all function's arithmetic will be based on this type, like multiply, add.

The java generic seems to be complicated for arithmetic since I switch between float and double is for the performance.

Is there any suggestion?

One function of the class:

```
public float calculate(float[] arr){
    float result = 0;
    for(float i : arr){
        result += i * i;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it's beneficial to be generic for float and double?

Comment: If you want to select between floats and doubles for performance reasons, generics will not help you. Since they require boxing up primitives into objects, they are unlikely to improve your performance. Your left with writing two versions of each function; or just sticking with doubles.

Comment: And how much benefit to do see performance-wise from switching between double and float in the first place?

Comment: It's a large scale cosine similarity score calculation(realtime is needed, there is an ANN search implementation already, but I want to speed up the cosine similarity calculation after searched.)

Comment: @StevenChou if you need the same logic for both types, codegen the methods.